# Is there a spell that creates a treant?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

Is it possible for a PC to create a treant without using a spell like *wish* or *miracle* or an epic spell?

Comment: Are you explicitly looking for Conjuration (Creation) or Conjuration (Summoning) spells?

Comment: @Chemus -- sorry about that, Maiko went off a wee bit half-cocked when I asked him about this in chat :)  the answer to your question is *yes*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Spells that create a [treant](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#treant)…

The 7th-level druid spell [***changestaff***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#changestaff) [trans] (*Player's Handbook* 208) allows the caster to turn a specially prepared walking stick into a virtual treant. Similarly but less portable, the 6th-level druid spell [***liveoak***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#liveoak) [trans] (*PH* 248) creates an ersatz treant guardian when a druid's near a sacred space.

More frighteningly, the 9th-level wu jen wood spell ***arboreal transformation*** [trans] (*Complete Mage* 95) for 1 day/level changes a creature into a treant that obeys the wu jen's commands; when the duration expires, the creature becomes a normal tree.

### …And, as alternatives, magic items that produce a treant

The ***sapling club*** (*Arms and Equipment Guide* 115) (32,450 gp; 3 lbs.) is a *+1 club* that the wielder can command to become for up to 12 rounds/day a treant, and the ***seeds of the treant*** (*AE* 136) (15,300 gp; 0 lbs.) brings forth from the planted seeds *instantaneously* a for-reals treant… over whom the planter has no control. (Apparently the *Guide* had a *serious* thing for treant-themed items. I mean, also see the *staff of trees* (*AE* 127) (120,000 gp; 4 lbs.). Who knew?)

Comment: Awaken also does the job, to some extent.

Comment: @BenBarden Balderdash! An awakened tree is just a big animated object not a true treant! (Although you're right that it may look like one.) And, I guess the spell *polymorph any object* could make a treant, too, but the spell *polymorph any object* is kind of a cop-out when other spells exist that actually do *specifically* create a treant rather than a spell that can create a treant or a mailbox or a 5-course meal or the caster's heart's desire. (Also, thank you for the opportunity to use the word *balderdash*. `:-)`)

Answer (score 5):

[Liveoak](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/liveoak.htm) (Druid 6):

> Liveoak must be cast on a healthy, Huge oak. A triggering phrase of up to one word per caster level is placed on the targeted oak. The liveoak spell triggers the tree into animating as a treant.

[Changestaff](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/changestaff.htm) (Druid 7):

> You change a specially prepared quarterstaff into a Huge treantlike creature, about 24 feet tall. When you plant the end of the staff in the ground and speak a special command to conclude the casting of the spell, your staff turns into a creature that looks and fights just like a treant.